# how to retrieve td value from xml using tcpdf

Tags: tcpdf

I have xml file with tables in it and i want to retrieve the TD value and save it inside variable using TCPDF.

any help would be great.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues, one: retrieve the td information, two: put inside the pdf.

To get the info of the td use simpleXML http://php.net/manual/es/book.simplexml.php, with this tool you can get the info of every tag in the xml.

Now, when you have this information, you can put this inside the pdf with tcpdf with Cell() function. Read the documentation of tdpdf if you have problems.

Other solution: If the xml has html, you can put the html inside the pdf with WriteHtml() function.

Comment: thanks David. i manage to extract the table tags from the xml files, however i am having problem with the table's width, is there any tcpdf function which will limit the width of the table ?